# Has there been a change in quota cost for Channels.list api call?

Tags: youtube-api

We use the channels list call to get stats about our customer's channels.  Starting late last week we noticed a huge increase in cost to make the api call.

The only part I'm using in the call is "statistics".  The quota tool only shows a cost of 3 points, but in testing it seems to be higher, closer to 50.  I noticed an API update was pushed out last last week but no mention of quota increase in the update note.  Is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you should report it directly to Google: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: Can you give an example of a call you made that cost around 50 points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out YT starting throwing a new exception that caused an increase in the api calls.